# Flush Redis database from remote batch file

Tags: batch-file, redis, flush

I need to setup a scheduled task to flush my Redis DB daily. In order to do this I was planning to create a batch file with commands to connect to my remote Redis Server and flush my specific DB, and then setup the Batch file in a scheduled task.

Currently I have

```
"%REDIS_PATH%\redis-cli" -h "serverName.somelocation.windows.net" -p 6380 -a SOMEPASSWORD ping
```

I was expecting this to return PONG, and then continue on from there to add the specific commands for flushing my DB. However, the ping command spins for a few seconds then returns nothing. No error or message or anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I have found a solution to my original problem. I have switched over to using a powershell script instead of a batch file. Someone from Microsoft published the script to flush remotely here: https://aaronsaikovski.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/how-to-flush-the-azure-redis-cache-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this command locally?

If so, it sounds like port 6380 on your remote machine isn't open to the public. This is probably a good thing.

You should run this command on the command line of the remote machine. You might be able to leave off the host entirely.

Comment: I am not running this locally. I need to be able to have this batch file run remotely.